# Pause hover-triggered finished animation

Tags: css

I have an animation that is triggered by hovering on a sibling element (an image that renders above the animated element with the `z-index` property), and wish to get it paused once it's finished, since when the mouse leaves said sibling element, the animation reverts to its origin state. However I can't figure out how to do that.

Here's a snippet:

```css
@keyframes boot {
  0% {
    background-color: black;
    color: black;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #001900;
    color: white;
  }
}

div.tablet {
  background-color: #666;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

div.tablet img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 15px;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

div.tablet br {
  display: none;
}

div.screen {
  background-color: black;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
  z-index: 0;
}

div.screen br {
  display: inline;
}

img:hover + div.screen {
  animation: boot 7s;
  background-color: #001900;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="tablet">
  <img src="http://insurrection-du-chaos-sandbox.wdfiles.com/local--files/s-ou-o/broken.png" />
  <div class="screen">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec feugiat fringilla dolor, vel rutrum arcu porttitor in. Suspendisse et ornare orci. Duis dictum lacinia condimentum. Cras sed mattis justo, eu convallis elit. Sed efficitur lectus vitae nisi blandit scelerisque. Nulla efficitur condimentum quam. Ut et faucibus metus. Quisque ornare tempor sapien, ac venenatis urna. Donec eget suscipit turpis. Nulla venenatis ultricies purus, et facilisis felis sollicitudin et. In aliquet auctor aliquet. Donec sit amet diam iaculis, ultricies nisi eget, eleifend nulla.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better solution will be to use `transition` and `transition-delay`.

```css
.tablet {
  background-color: #666;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.tablet img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 15px;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.tablet br {
  display: none;
}

.screen {
  background-color: black;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
  z-index: 0;

  transition: .4s ease-out;
  transition-delay: 2s;
  /* or only transition: .4s ease-out 2s;*/
}

.screen br {
  display: inline;
}

img:hover+.screen {
  transition: .4s ease-out;

  background-color: #001900;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tablet">
    <img src="http://insurrection-du-chaos-sandbox.wdfiles.com/local--files/s-ou-o/broken.png" />
    <div class="screen">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec feugiat fringilla dolor, vel rutrum arcu porttitor
      in. Suspendisse et ornare orci. Duis dictum lacinia condimentum. Cras sed mattis justo, eu convallis elit. Sed
      efficitur lectus vitae nisi blandit scelerisque. Nulla efficitur condimentum quam. Ut et faucibus metus. Quisque
      ornare tempor sapien, ac venenatis urna. Donec eget suscipit turpis. Nulla venenatis ultricies purus, et facilisis
      felis sollicitudin et. In aliquet auctor aliquet. Donec sit amet diam iaculis, ultricies nisi eget, eleifend
      nulla.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```